# query about $resource and query parameters

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs 1.6, and trying to create a url using this format

```
http://localhost:49524//api/products/GDN
```

where GDN is a parameter I wish to specify.

I have this working using `$resource` set up as:

```
$resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:id", { id: '@id' });
```

And my controller contains:

```
productResource.query({id: vm.searchCriteria}, (data)=> {
        vm.products = data;
     });
```

I have tried renaming id to 'search'.  However when I do so, the url generated becomes:

```
http://localhost:49524//api/products?search=GDN
```

Could someone suggest what I am I missing?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why `search` is added as a query string  ?

```
http://localhost:49524//api/products?search=GDN
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

From docs [angular#resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search query after the ?.

In the `productResource.query`,`search` is there.But the this param is not defined in `resource` defination.

You have to rename it in [angular#resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) definition as well.

```
$resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:search", { search: '@id' });
                                                    ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^
```

controller :

```
productResource.query({search: vm.searchCriteria}, (data)=> {
                       ^^^^^^
        vm.products = data;
     });
```

If yo dont rename it in resource defination,it will added as query string

EDIT :

```
$resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:search", { search: '@id' });                                              
                                                   ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment Ritchie.  However, here is a plunker that illustrates the issue

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/aQGMCHEa5EUvzhpDryio?p=preview
```

If I change the code as you suggested:

```
return $resource('/api/~:username/article/:id', {
 search: '@id',
 username: Authorization.currentUser
})
```

and

```
ctrl.testResource = function() {
Article.get({search: 5});
};
```

then the url becomes:
    http://run.plnkr.co/api/~dave/article?search=5

Comment: Thanks Ritchie.  I think I also had a couple of other issues that were confusing the problem.  I'm running using IISExpress, and sometimes I had to restart the server as the javascript changes were not reloaded.  Also, within Chrome, I had to select 'Disable cache'.  Thanks for your help!!